# Teshuva for intercourse with non Jew

Tags: gentiles, sexuality, sin, repentance-teshuvah, reincarnation

This question is different than the one people think is a duplicate because the other one doesn’t necessarily answer the questions I’m asking.

If someone has intercourse with a non Jew even if he never meant to do it and he was seduced in the moment and regrets it, teshuva takes away all the sin but I heard the souls stay attached until shamayim. Does teshuva also take that part away? And if not is there a way?

This was also a question but wasn’t answered. Also I heard someone is reincarnated into a dog if he doesn’t do teshuvah so if he does teshuva will it be cleared and he won’t be a dog.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the part about the souls and the dog part can u answer that here ?

Comment: I edited the question can it be answered please I’m desperate help another yid out

Comment: Can you provide some source for this _soul attachement_ stuff? I've never heard of it.

Comment: And reincarnation was introduced into Judiasm a few hundred years ago - I wouldn't lose too much sleep over it.

Comment: The Ramchal in Derech Hashem seems to indicate that Jewish souls can only be human.

Comment: I don’t know people said that Ure soul is connected like rabbi Mizrachi said it